# Best way to track new fields ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: sql, postgresql, asp.net-core, database-design, entity-framework-core

I have a database that tracks vendors and jobs. For each job I have spots in my database for four set vendors and all of their information. What would be the best way to account for a fifth vendor? Should I edit my database and add a bunch of extra fields for potentially additional vendors? Or would I create a field that only lives in a C# class or something similar? My application is a database first design if that matters.

*edit*
Using Entity Framework Core and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

This question is more about database architecture rather than programming.

It sounds like you might be stuck with a less-than-ideal database schema. So you might just have to deal with it and add another vendor in the same way the others were defined if you can't restructure your database schema.

I'll describe the "right" way to do it. The main benefit of doing it this way is not duplicating data (if I understand you right, then if one vendor works on several jobs, then you have the vendor data duplicated on each job).

When you have two entities like "vendors" and "jobs" that are related to each other, then you would usually have tables for each (a Vendors table and a Jobs table).

If each job can be handled by several vendors, and each vendor can work on several jobs, then that's called a "many-to-many" relationship and usually a separate table is created with two columns (VendorId and JobId) to define the relationship.

If you are using Entity Framework, then EF can handles many-to-many relationships using a collection: Each Vendor would have a Jobs property, which is a collection of Jobs that the vendor is involved in. Likewise, each Job would have a Vendors collection. You don't actually need to see the mapping table in your code.

More information about how to handle relationships in SQL is [here](https://database.guide/the-3-types-of-relationships-in-database-design/).

How relationships are defined and used in Entity Framework is discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) (that's specific to EF6, but the principals are the same in EF Core).

Comment: Okay, I'll look into my database more. As it stands, it is very structured, and does not allow a great deal of flexibility.